# Deleting from database raises Request failed with status code 405 error

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, axios

I am attempting to delete items from a MySQL database by id using axios. In my Vue component I have the following method set up to handle removing an item:

```
deleteTodo(id, index){
        axios.delete('api/todos/' + id).then(function(response){
             console.log(response)
             this.todos.slice(index, 1)
        }.bind(this)).catch((err) => {
              console.log(err)
        })       
}
```

I am calling deleteTodo in my template like so:

```
 <li v-for="(todo, index) in todos">
     <span>{{todo.todo}} <button @click="deleteTodo(todo.id, index)">delete</button></span>
 </li>
```

In my `TodoController` I have the following method:

```
 public function remove($id)
 {
    DB::table('todos')->where('id', $id)->delete();
    return redirect('todos');
 }
```

If I attempt to delete an item, I get the following error in the console:

```
Error: Request failed with status code 405
Stack trace:
createError@http://localhost:8000/js/app.js line 107 > eval:15:15
settle@http://localhost:8000/js/app.js line 193 > eval:18:12
handleLoad@http://localhost:8000/js/app.js line 86 > eval:77:7
```

If I refresh the browser, it app items are indeed being deleted (I also can confirm they are being deleted by visiting api/todos route). However, I have to hit the delete button twice and refresh the browser for it to actually delete the item from the database.

Why am I getting this error, and how do I fix it?

Comment: When you get the 405 response, what Access-Control-Allow-Methods are listed in the response headers?

Comment: did you setup CORS ?

Comment: @ScottSchupbach Allow: "GET, HEAD"

Comment: @imrealashu Would I do that at the application level in laravel?

Comment: @MahmudAdam yeah, http://en.vedovelli.com.br/2015/web-development/Laravel-5-1-enable-CORS/ this is the easiest way to go and it works fine.

Comment: So then the real question is why is the resource being removed from the database if DELETE is not an allowed method. Is it possible that the request is being made more than once? Can you check the preserve log box in the network console (in Chrome; for Firefox enable persistent logs in settings) and check for multiple DELETE requests.

Comment: @ScottSchupbach I just noticed that I have to click the delete button twice and refresh the browser for it to actually remove it from the database. I am not sure what the error is here.

Comment: Can you change your return statement like `return response()->json('deleted');`. In your api routes, make sure you have `Route::delete('todos/{id}', 'TodoController@remove');`. If everything is setup correctly, make sure you didn't define a route more than once.

Comment: @EddyTheDove That fixed the 405 error. Thanks!

Comment: Should I make it as an answer so you mark my answer as the solution ? To assure everyone else having the same issue finds the solution easily. And what part exactly changed fixed it? the return response or the route definition?

Comment: I would make it an answer; specifically, the return response.

Comment: @MahmudAdam, please select my answer as it helped you. You promised you would make it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem most probably comes from HTTP redirect with `return redirect('todos');` whereas the request is a JSON/AJAX request (from Vue component using axios), and therefore should return a JSON response. Changing the return statement to `return response()->json('Deleted');` should do the trick.